# Maximum flow minimum cut

Tags: linear-programming, network-flow

For the following problem I am trying to find maximum flow and minimum cut:

[image]

I found the maximum flow as 6 like this:

$1-3-7-8:2 flows$

$1-2-5-8: 2 flows$

$1-3-4-5-8:1 flow$

$1-3-4-6-5-8:1 flow$

But I am having trouble to match the min cut, I thought it would be 8(by cutting the following arcs $(7,8)$ and $(5,8))$. How do I match the min cut? Or do you think I made a mistake finding max flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum flow is $6$.  To find a corresponding minimum cut, note that $S=\{1,3,4,7\}$ is the set of nodes reachable from the source node $1$ in the residual network.  Now consider the arcs from $S$ to $N\setminus S$.

Comment: We took the following arcs, right? I am asking to make sure. (1-2),(4-5),(4-6),(7-8).

Comment: Yes, those are correct, with sum of capacities equal to $2+1+1+2=6$, matching the flow value.